# locking with compare and swap on a boolean

Tags: c++11, atomic, compare-and-swap

I am experimenting the `atomic_compare_and_swap` function to do a basic lock on a `std::atomic<bool>`.

The behaviour I was expecting is that the second thread i.e `Consume` would remain blocked in the `while` loop at the beginning of `Access::get()` for all the time the atomic `lock_` is set to `true`.

Due to the `sleeps` I've introduced it is always the first thread `Produce` to set the atomic to `true` to prevent the second thread to proceed.

Unfortunately this is not the case and I can see that the second thread executes immediately and doesn't remain blocked at all.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using `g++4.9 on Lubuntu`

```
class Access
{
  atomic<bool> lock_;
  bool         UNLOCKED_;

public:
  Access() : lock_(false), UNLOCKED_(false){}

  void set()
  {
    // lock
    while(!atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&lock_, &UNLOCKED_, true)) {}                 
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));      
    cout << "set" << endl;   
  }

  void get()
  {
    // lock
    while(!atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&lock_, &UNLOCKED_, true)){} 
    cout << "get" << endl;        
  }
};

Access gTest; // global

void Produce() { gTest.set(); }

void Consume() { gTest.get(); }

int main() {
  thread producer(Produce);
  this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
  thread consumer(Consume);
  producer.join();
  consumer.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're using an `atomic` object (`lock_`), why don't you use `lock_.compare_exchange_strong()`?

Comment: @Alejandro: I did that just because when I google for C++11 Compare And Swap those are the 2 free functions that come out on firs positions and I gave it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the producer thread executes `set()` and the CAS loop, it will see that the value of `UNLOCKED_` and `lock_` are the same (`false`), sets `lock_` to true, and returns true. Thus,the loop exits and this thread waits for 20 seconds.

At the same time, the 3 second delay you imposed with

```
this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
```

in main() is still ticking and when it expires, the consumer thread executes `get()` and the CAS loop will first see that `UNLOCKED_` is `false` but `lock_` is true (because it was set by the producer), and so it updates the value of `UNLOCKED_` to `true` and spins again. On the next iteration of the CAS loop, it will see that both `lock_` and `UNLOCKED_` are now `true` (`UNLOCKED_` was set in the previous iteration), and the loop breaks out.

Comment: Auch! I am very sorry as It seems I missed to read the second line of the documentation for that function, Thanks for your help.